Because Samson did not Drink, Every Strange act that he did was Imputed to a Higher Purpose?
Abarbanel in Chapter 13 of Judges:
וגם לסבה אחרת והיא לפי שהיה גלוי לפניו הדברים הזרים שהיה עתיד שמשון לעשותו, רצה יתברך שלא יחשוב אדם שיהיו מעשה שכרות,
"and also for another reason (was Samson prohibited to drink) ... it was revealed before God the strange acts that Samson was going to perform, and God wanted that no one should think these acts were due to intoxication .. . ."
Who cares if Shimshon accomplished everything that he did, but people thought he was a drunkard? You mean to say that people did not think he was off and going berserk because he didn't drink? But the acts were strange and there's millions of reasons for people to say things. You mean that if I don't have an external thing - alcohol - to pin his actions on, I'm going to impute every strange and raging act of his to God?

Shimshon's life's mission was to convince the Israelites, and especially Judah, to stop cowering and attack the Philistines. If they thought he was a loony drunk they would have never stopped to think that perhaps he was acting in a strategic manner (which he was) and maybe they should follow him.

@ Harel13 thx. And if they thought he was a loony insane person they were going to follow him?

The opposite- they wouldn't have followed him if he was a known drunkard.
